# What's the difference 'He saved a seat for me'' and 'He saved a seat to me.'?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference

**- 'He saved a seat for me.'**

**and**

**- 'He saved a seat to me.'?**

Answer (score 1):

**'He saved a seat for me.' is grammatically correct.**

The phrase implies a male reserving a seat on behalf of someone else.

**'He saved a seat to me.' doesn't seem to be grammatically correct.**

This sentence does not mean the same as above, though you may possibly be able to interpret it along the lines of reserving a seat while thinking of you?

Comment: Yup. That's the main difference. _He saved a seat for me_ is a grammatical sentence in English, and *_He saved a seat to me_ is not. The idiom _save `X` for `Y`_  is a [benefactive usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299) of _for_.

Answer (score 0):

'He saved a seat for me' is correct English and makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add sources to support your answers.